# Is there an equivalent to the lsusb command using System.IO.Ports in .NET 6?

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi

I am developing an application on a Raspberry Pi OS Lite in Visual Studio .NET 6.0 and need to read the USB Ports.

When I SSH into the Raspberry Pi 4.0B target and enter the `lsusb` command, I see the following list:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0c76:161e JMTek, LLC. USB PnP Audio Device Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I would like to use `System.IO.Ports` to find the USB port where the `JMTek, LLC. USB Audio Device Hub` is plugged in.

I tried the code below:

```
   public void EnumPorts()
    {
        private string[]? portNames;

        portNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        Console.WriteLine("Port Count {0}:", portNames.Length);

        foreach(var port in portNames) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(port);
        }

    }
```

However, when `System.IO.SerialPort.GetPortNames()` is executed a single entry is returned:

`/dev/ttyAMA0`

Is there a way to obtain the same information returned by the `lsusb` command with the .NET 6.0 System.IO.Ports (or other) namespace?

**Update**

To enumerate the USB Ports on the Raspberry Pi 4, I wrote the following function and use a `GetFiles` in place of `GetPortNames`.

```
   public void EnumUSBPorts()
    {
        
        string[] ttys = Directory.GetFiles("/dev/bus/usb/001", "*");

        foreach (string device in ttys)
        {
                usbNames.Add(device);
                Console.WriteLine(device);
        }
    }
```

In this case, it returns a list of all USB ports on Bus `001`.

This seems to list all of the USB's on Bus 001.

Comment: System.Management is normally used for this kind of info, but it is not implemented for Unix.  Consider using lsusb, run it with the Process class and parse its output.

Comment: This is an audio device. Are you sure it presents itself as serial port?

Comment: If I can grant myself permission to the USB port, I think I am there...

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight-forward, you have to use the `ManagementObjectCollection` and send the query `Select * From Win32_USBHub`. Use the code below and check if the port you need will show up, since I can't test on my side.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;

namespace USBLoader
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var usbDevices = GetUSBDevices();

            foreach (var usbDevice in usbDevices)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Device ID: {0}, PNP Device ID: {1}, Description: {2}",
                    usbDevice.DeviceID, usbDevice.PnpDeviceID, usbDevice.Description);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
        static List<USBDeviceInfo> GetUSBDevices()
        {
            List<USBDeviceInfo> devices = new List<USBDeviceInfo>();

            ManagementObjectCollection collection;
            using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_USBHub"))
                collection = searcher.Get();

            foreach (var device in collection)
            {
                devices.Add(new USBDeviceInfo(
                (string)device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID"),
                (string)device.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID"),
                (string)device.GetPropertyValue("Description")
                ));
            }

            collection.Dispose();
            return devices;
        }
    }
    class USBDeviceInfo
    {
        public USBDeviceInfo(string deviceID, string pnpDeviceID, string description)
        {
            this.DeviceID = deviceID;
            this.PnpDeviceID = pnpDeviceID;
            this.Description = description;
        }
        public string DeviceID { get; private set; }
        public string PnpDeviceID { get; private set; }
        public string Description { get; private set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Will `Win32_USBHub` work on a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @gunr2171 That's why I asked for to test it, since that's the only command that seems fit to work in USB Hubs.

Comment: I will test it and post a note back.

Comment: Note the edits to the main question.